# ASP simple program

Tags: logic

In the following Program:

```
ide_drive       :- hard_drive, not scsi_drive.
scsi_drive      :- hard_drive, not ide_drive.
scsi_controller :- scsi_drive.
hard_drive.
```

The stable models are:

```
M1 = {hard_drive, ide_drive}
M2 = {hard_drive, scsi_drive, scsi_controller}
```

> An stable model tells which atoms are true.

Why M1 and M2 are stable models of the given program?

Comment: Are you sure you asked this question in the proper forum?  I'm not sure the proper venue for this question, but it looks like a computer science question.

Comment: Is this a maths question ?

Comment: Looks like Prolog syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call the variables $A,B,C,D$. So we are given
$$
\begin{align*}
A &\leftrightarrow D \land \lnot B \\
B &\leftrightarrow D \land \lnot A \\
C &\leftrightarrow B \\
D &
\end{align*}
$$

So $D$ must be true. Also, $C = B$. The program simplifies to $A \leftrightarrow \lnot B$. So exactly one of $A,B$ is true. If $A$ is true then $B,C$ are false, and conversely, if $A$ is false then $B,C$ are true. So the "stable models" are
$$
\{A,D\}, \quad \{B,C,D\}.
$$

Comment: An incomprehensible question with a neat, well-written answer. Service above and beyond the call of duty. Well done.

Comment: How sure are you that the `:-` stands for $\leftrightarrow$ here? In ordinary logic programming it usually means $\leftarrow$.

Comment: Henning, you're right. It works even with $\leftarrow$. Though in this case you'd need to define stable models differently, so that $\{A,C,D\}$ is not one.